# error: ld returned 1 exit status - codeblocks

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I downloaded the source of a small openGL project but when i try to compile it gives me this error message ("error: ld returned 1 exit status") and i dont know how to fix it. Does anyone know what it means? 
The program uses openGL with GLFW 2.

Here's the build log:

-------------- Build: Debug in Procedurus (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib" -o bin\Debug\Procedurus.exe obj\Debug\Application\TextTool.o obj\Debug\Geometry\AstronomicalObject.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Atmosphere.o obj\Debug\Geometry\CloudLayer.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Frustum.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Geometry.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Particle2D.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Planet.o obj\Debug\Geometry\PlanetRing.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\QuadtreeTerrain.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\QuadtreeTerrainFace.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\QuadtreeTerrainNode.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\QuadtreeTerrainPatch.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\QuadtreeTerrainPatchTopology.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\RidgedMultifractalSphericalQuadtreeTerrain.o obj\Debug\Geometry\QuadtreeTerrain\SphericalQuadtreeTerrain.o obj\Debug\Geometry\SimpleCircle.o obj\Debug\Geometry\SimpleCylinder.o obj\Debug\Geometry\SimpleDisk.o obj\Debug\Geometry\SimpleSphere.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Skybox.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Star.o obj\Debug\Geometry\Starfield.o obj\Debug\GL\GLee.o obj\Debug\Math\Randomizer.o obj\Debug\ProcedurusMain.o obj\Debug\Shaders\ShaderManager.o   -lopengl32 -lglfw -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lGLFW GL/glfw

GL/glfw: file not recognized: File format not recognized

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

So the problem is with the file named "glfw" but if i delete it and keep only the glfw.h it gives me another error ("mingw32-g++.exe: error: GL/glfw: No such file or directory
")

I can upload the project if that helps.

Comment: What were the error messages appearing before?

Comment: It means that the linker didn't find all parts needed to build the program. The amount of info you provided isn't enough to tell *what* parts.

Comment: From what you show us here it is absolutely impossible to tell whats wrong. Which call to ld produces this output? Aren't there any other messages in the log? Please provide the complete log.

Comment: it doesnt say anything else beside this message

Comment: Then show which line you execute to compile the program. It is not even clear which environment you are using. Are you compiling from the command line? Which compiler? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @AlexBan _"it doesnt say anything else beside this message"_ That's very unlikely.

Comment: @BDL OP compiles from IDE, but there should be a window with the complete commands and error messages.

Comment: heres a screenshot with the build message : http://imgur.com/a/fCHDA

Comment: @AlexBan You will find the build log in the **Build log** tab - not in the **Build messages** tab. Post the complete build log in the body of your question.

Comment: @MikeKinghan i've posted the build log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `GL/glfw` in your compile command, you should delete this, it is not necessary.